# Using ALSA on Firefox instead of PulseAudio

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio, alsa

Since Firefox [version >=52](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/52.0/releasenotes/), the browser has dropped support for [ALSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture) and depends solely on PulseAudio for sound requirements, hence rendering all sites playing audio broken on an  ALSA-only system (such as Lubuntu, an official Ubuntu Flavor).

Mozilla has cited ongoing problems and maintenance issues for dropping ALSA support, as explained in the [original bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1247056). This gives the options of either downgrading to an earlier version of Firefox (not really) or switching to a different browser.

Answer (score 1):

This known issue can be solved by installing `apulse`, the PulseAudio emulation for ALSA package.

1. Copy the Firefox Launcher to special folder inside home

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications/
   cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop`
   ```
2. Open desktop-file with editor by

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop
   ```
3. Modify `Exec=firefox %u` to `Exec=/usr/bin/apulse firefox %u` and save the file.

Above will force Firefox to use the apulse library every time Firefox is launched.